# SQL Simple Join Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]I am new in SQL. I am reading *Fundamentals of Database Systems* by Elmasri.
I am studying a very simple select-project-join. Here is one example in this book.
Query description:

> For every project located in ‘Stafford’, list the project number, the
>   controlling department number, and the department manager’s last name,
>   address, and birth date.

```
SELECT Pnumber, Dnum, Lname, Address, Bdate
FROM PROJECT, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE Dnum=Dnumber AND Mgr_ssn=Ssn AND
Plocation=‘Stafford’;
```

Relation data base schema is attached.

Here is my question: Does it have to be `Dnum=Dnumber AND Mgr_ssn=ssn`? why not `Dnum=Dnumber AND Dno=Dnumber`?

Comment: You should learn to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of cross-product syntax.

Comment: You also have the wrong types of quotes around `Stafford`. You should always disable Smart Quotes when you're editing code.

Comment: That was from the book. For some reason, the author covers this stuff first and did not explain it much in detail yet. So why wouldn't Dno=Dnumer work instead of Mgr_ssn=ssn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Dno = Dnumber` you'll get *all* the employees in the department, not just the manager of the department.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, because the description say that

> ... list **the department manager**’s last name, address, and birth date

So using `Mgr_ssn=Ssn` to join is a **sufficent condition**. Because of table design, It implicit has the **necessary condition** `Dno=Dnumber`, so you may (or may not) need to add it to you query.

And one more, your book is a little old, you should considering read some external links like [avoiding using old style join](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and [using table alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)